# Дата и время

Tags: .net, c#

Есть дата в формате string: "04 мая 2011". Необходимо преобразовать в DateTime. Convert.ToDateTime - не пашет. 
Я на C# раньше почти не писал и возникает вопрос: какой формат даты должен быть представлен в строке для успешной конвертации(прошу, если не трудно привести пример максимально подобный к моему)? Или может представленный мною формат есть вполне принятым и Я что-то не так делаю?

**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для конвертирования данных специфичных для разных культур необходимо культуру указывать параметром метода, который ты используешь. Что касается конверсии строки в DateTime, то подробную информацию можно прочитать [в этой статье MSDN: Parsing Date and Time Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx).

Надеюсь, поможет разобраться.